# ¿Cómo funciona el condicional if (!+[]+!+[] == 2) en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo funciona este código? Quisiera una explicación detallada si es posible y saber dónde hay documentación al respecto.

```js
if (!+[]+!+[] == 2) {
  document.write('Somos iguales');
}
else {
  document.write('Somos distintos');
}
```

Comment: Aunque ya tienes varias y excelentes respuestas olvidaron mencionar que deberías evitar el uso de `document.write()` en producción.

Comment: Porque debo evitar su uso?

Comment: [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Un `Array` vacio es igual a `false`

```
[] == false
```

el contrario de `false` es `true`

```
!false == true
```

`true` es igual a 1, `false` es igual a 0

```
true == 1
false == 0
```

entonces

```
true + true == 2
```

```js
function probar(){
    console.log([] == false);
    console.log(!false == true);
    console.log(true == 1)
    console.log(false == 0)
    console.log(true + true == 2)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="probar()">probar</button>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias , me podrias decir donde aprender javascript practicamente y de buena forma? porfavor

Comment: `Herramientas para desarrolladores -> Console` y trastea con todos los sitios...

Comment: Sí `console.log([])` devuelve `false`, `console.log(! [])` debería dar como resultado `true` , **pero no es así , ¿por qué?**

Comment: @dev.joel al parecer []==false, se refiere a que esta vacio, pero Boolean([])==true indica que el elemento existe, por que Boolean(null) da false, el operador ! es equivalente a !Boolean([])

Comment: Leyendo, todo valor en javascript es true, menos null, undefined, number zero y boolean false, que dan false

Comment: soy de php y he entendido esta explicación

Comment: Con la explicación actual entonces `![]+![]` también debería evaluar a `2` pero evalúa a `0`, se ha obviado por completo el hecho de que se está usando el operador suma ([unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())) para convertir los arrays vacíos en números (ceros) dando lugar al resultado esperado `2`

Comment: La explicación dada a @Dev.Joel acerca de `Boolean([])` es incorrecta, `Boolean` usado como función convierte en `false` a cualquier valor pasado como parámetro exceptuando `0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined` ([documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)). Este y el anterior comentario son las razones por las que estoy dando puntos negativos a esta respuesta

Comment: Recién acabo de leer la respuesta de @Dev.Joel y de Rubén :P, es la respuesta correcta

Comment: No se hace mención del primer `+` ni de su uso como operador unitario.

Comment: @LeonPlata, creo que has mal interpretado el texto que has leído o has escrito lo contrario de lo que querías poner. Al utilizar `Boolean` cualquier cosa que le pases es evaluada a `true`, excptuando `0`, `-0`, `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `document.all` o un string vacío. La explicación de @Dev.Joel dice que `Boolean([])` da `true` y esto es cierto.

Comment: @ElChiniNet, erróneamente he escrito lo contrario de lo que quería expresar y por ello mi comentario es invalido, gracias por la aclaración

Comment: @LeonPlata, eso imaginé. Un saludo ;)

Answer (score 57):

**`JSFuck`** es un estilo de programación **esotérico** y **educativo** basado en las partes atómicas de **JavaScript**.

Algunas reglas  para recordar:

- Precediendo con `!` convertimos a valor `Booleano`

  ```
  console.log(![])   // return false
  ```
- Precediendo con `+`  convertimos a número

  ```
  console.log(+[])  // return 0
  ```
- Adición `[]` convertimos a Cadena

  ```
  console.log([]+[])  // return  ""
  ```

> Por qué muestra el Mensaje son Iguales?

- `!+[]` al anteponer el signo más se convierte en número , `+[] = 0` la negación `(!)` de **0 es 1.**

Luego al realizar la suma  `!+[]    +   !+[]` es decir `1+1 = 2`

Referencias

- http://www.jsfuck.com/
- http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html
- http://www.jazcash.com/a-javascript-journey-with-only-six-characters/

Comment: Esta interesante tu respuesta :), por cierto no has leido sobre que la suma + se aplkca de defecha a izquierda jejeje no se donde lo lei, por eso pense que era algo asi []+ o da igual.?

Comment: Está especificado en mi respuesta de la adición a la izquierda y derecha. **a la derecha espera de otro valor para efectuar la suma** por lo tanto `[]+` dará un error de sintaxis , y a la izquierda se convierte a número.

Comment: ¿Pero por qué `[]` vale `true`?  Si creo una variable `a = 0` y luego hago `if (!a) console.log('Hola')` se imprime `Hola`, porque `0` es `false`... pero `+[]` devuelve `0` y es `true` ¿al mismo tiempo? Con razón se llama _JSFuck_ 0_o...

Comment: ¿No va un poco en contra de todo lo que defiende el código limpio (clean code)?. Se puede entender ese código pero siempre pienso que un código que no se lee fácil de un vistazo rápido no es buena idea :S.

Comment: @erknrio no es una buena idea , solo plantee que existe tal estilo de programación , por qué se obtiene el resultado planteado.

Comment: @Dev.Joel, si si, entendí su postura. Simplemente era un comentario general. A veces lo que uno piensa no es siempre lo mejor y quería saber la opinión de otros :-).

Comment: Hola @toledano, lee mi respuesta más abajo. Creo que aclara tus dudas. Un saludo

Comment: @Victor-Random, las sumas se aplican de izquierda a derecha a no ser que sitúes paréntesis para variar ese comportamiento. Es por eso que `2 + 3 + "0"` da `50` en vez de `230`. Me imagino que es eso lo que debes haber leído. Como bien dice Dev.Joel si sitúas el operador `+` a la derecha de un operando, debes situar un segundo operando o te dará error.

Answer (score 30):

> Los enlaces incluídos a continuación indicados con <sup>1</sup> corresponden a secciones de [ECMAScript® 2016 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html). La intención en primera instancia es proporcionar las referencias específicas al estándar referido, utilizando un enfoque de "jalar" (pull) más que el tradicional de "empujar" (push)

A continuación se listan las referencias correspondientes a cada una de las partes principales de

```
!+[]+!+[] == 2
```

Las cuales son

- `[]` expresión para inicializar un objeto literal de tipo matriz, equivalente a `new Array()`.
- `+[]` matriz con operador unitario +.
- `!+[]` matriz con operador unitario + y operador unitario no lógico.
- `!+[]  +  !+[]` adición de dos `!+[]` .
- `!+[]  +  !+[]   ==   2` comparación abstracta de la adición de dos `!+[]`.

Empecemos

- En [Array Initializer](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer) se indica que `[]` inicializa un literal de tipo matriz con ningún elemento. La propiedad longitud (`length`) de la matriz es cero. y el valor primitivo es un cadena vacía. Para más detalles véase la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67342/65) a [¿Cuál es el valor primitivo de [] con base en ECMAScript 2016 (versión 7)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67171/65).
- En [Unary + operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-unary-plus-operator)<sup>1</sup> se indica que `+` convierte su operando a tipo número. En el caso de `+ []` , el operando es una cadena vacía (probando `[].join() === ''` en la consola de Chrome devuelve `true`) y al convertir este a número, se convierte en `0`.

  - Véase [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67342/65) [¿Cuál es el valor primitivo de [] con base en ECMAScript 2016 (versión 7)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67171/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-valor-primitivo-de-con-base-en-ecmascript-2016-versi%c3%b3n-7?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- En [logical operator not](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator)<sup>1</sup> se indica que `!` convierte su operando a tipo booleano, y que si el valor booleano del operando es falso, devuelve verdadero y si el valor booleano del operando es verdadero, devuelve falso.
- En [ToBoolean](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toboolean)<sup>1</sup> se indica que cuando el valor es cero (`-0` ó `+0`), se devuelve falso (`false`).
- En [The Addition Operator ( + )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus)<sup>1</sup> se indica que cuando los operandos son de tipo distinto a cadena de texto,  se convierten a número.
- En [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)<sup>1</sup> se indica que cuando el valor es verdadero, se devuelve uno (`1`) y cuando el valor es falso, se devuelve cero (`0`).
- En [Applying the Additive Operators to Numbers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers)<sup>1</sup> se indica que cuando `+` se aplica a dos operandos numéricos, realiza la adición de estos.
- En [Abstract equality comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)<sup>1</sup> se indica que cuando los dos elementos a la izquierda y derecha son iguales, devuelve verdadero (`true`)y en caso contrario devuelve falso (`false`).

Entonces

- `+[]` es una operación unitaria que devuelve cero (`0`)
- `!0` es una operación unitaria que devuelve verdadero (`true`)
- `true + true` es una operación que, primero convierte cada operando a `1` y luego devuelve su adición la cual es `2`
- `2 == 2` es una comparación de igualdad abstracta que devuelve verdadero (`true`)

A continuación un pequeño experimento para que el lector compruebe si stack-snippet y su navegador operan conforme a la especificación referida.

```js
document.write(+[]);
document.write('<br/>'); //Separador
document.write(!+[]);
document.write('<br/>'); //Separador
document.write(!+[]+!+[]);
```

Comment: FYI, `[]` es un array vacio. Nada que ver con el tipo `string`. Creo que podrias explicar la precedencia de operadores como para cerrar bien la respuesta.

Comment: @EmanuelVe en ciertos casos los objetos se convierten a [valores primitivos](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-primitive-value) ¿sabes cuál es el valor primitivo de un `[]`?

Comment: `[]` es un syntax-sugar para `new Array()` que si haces `typeof []` veras es q es un object. el tipo primitivo

Comment: Gracias pero según entiendo eso no responde mi pregunta. Un array es un objeto exótico el cual debe tener una regla para ser convertido a un tipo primitivo (Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, Symbol, or String).

Comment: es un object. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type

Comment: "An object is a collection of properties and has a single prototype object. The prototype may be the null value." pero me parece que no es el caso de `[]`. Bueno, no estoy buscando el prototipo, sino el valor primitivo.

Comment: @Rubén , [ ] esto, es una version corta para crear un array, en vez de new Array(). Un array es un object, si revisas mi respuesta veras su conversion a primitivo. Pasa por number y luego to primitive y luego segun el contenido pasadonpor el argumento te devuelve string o un entero.nese array vacío se vuelve string

Comment: @Victor-Random: He agregado la referencia sobre [].

Comment: @Rubén lo revisare.... :) ya entiendo que entonces el array no entraria en esa validacion del toprimitive, sino usando el join

Answer (score 18):

Para complementar a las respuestas, consideremos la siguiente serie de elementos adicionales documentados en:

> ECMA-262 7ᵗʰ Edition / June 2016 ECMAScript® 2016 Language Specification:
> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures.
>
> JavaScript in Plain Language - Tony de Araujo:
> [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NQERIEI/ref=rdr_kindle_ext_tmb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NQERIEI)
>
> JavaScript Objects Functions and Arrays Explained  - Tony de Araujo:
> [https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Objects-Functions-Arrays-Explained-ebook/dp/B00GDEPBZQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GDEPBZQ)
>
> Nicholas C. Zakas Professional JavaScript for Web Developers.
> https://www.amazon.es/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Wrox-Guides/dp/1118026691

---

**1) JavaScript datos primitivos y complejos:**

JavaScript basa sus tipos de datos de ECMAScript, divididos en primitivos y complejos o referenciados:

**Datos primitivos:**

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-primitive-value

- **String**: unicode, ascii y caracteres alfanuméricos.
- **Number**: integer, float.
- **Boolean**: true y false.
- **Null**: null.
- **Undefined**: undefined.

**Datos complejos:**

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-object

- **Object**: Array, Unordered list (Key-value, Map), funciones, object.

---

**2) Valores Booleanos de los datos:**

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#table-10

**Datos primitivos:**

`var string="Hola soy una string";` devolverá `true`.

`var integer=123;` devolverá `true`.

`var trueVariable = true;` devolverá `true`.

`var float = 4.98;` devolverá true.

**Datos complejos:**

`var arraySinElementos = [];` devolverá `true`.

`var arrayConElementos = [0,1,2];` devolverá `true`.

**Excepciones**:

Basándonos en la tabla anteriormente citada podremos encontrar los valores Booleanos de los siguientes tipos de datos, al aplicar `ToBoolean()`:

- **Boolean false**: devolverá `false`.
- **Number zero**: devolverá false.
- **Undefined**: devolverá false.
- **Null**: devolverá false.

---

**2) Valor de los operadores lógicos:**

Definimos los principales valores lógicos:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-boolean-value

```
true == 1;

false == 0;
```

**Operador lógico `not (!)`:** aplica la inversa del valor recibido.

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator

Su funcionamiento seria el siguiente :

```
resultado = !expresion;

!expresion == !(ToBoolean(expresion))
```

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation

La expresión sera evaluada con un `ToBoolean()`, que seguirá la siguiente tabla:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#table-10

Aplicando la inversa tendremos que:

- En el caso de ser la expresión `true` este devolverá `false`.
- En el caso de ser `false` devolverá `true`.
- Si es distinto de cero (`!==0`), el resultado es cero.
- Si es 0 el resultado sera 1.
- Las cadenas se convierten en números, si es posible.
- Las cadenas vacías se convierten en `true`.
- El valor lógico nulo o not realiza por determinado la  acción de `false`, ya que no se sabe si la condición es verdadera.

---

**3) Operador más unario (+expresion) y operador más de adición (expresión + expresión):**

El operador más (+) lo podemos encontrar como operador **unario** y de **adición**:

- Si se considera como adición:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus

- Si lo consideramos unario tendría la siguiente propiedad y funcionamiento:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation

```
expresión unaria: +expresión unaria
expresión unaria: ToNumber(expresión unaria)
```

Esta función aplicara `ToNumber()` a la expresión:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#table-11

Si se usa sobre un valor *no numérico* este aplicara la funcion `ToNumber()`, en nuestra caso tenemos un `array[]` que entraria en los datos referenciados o `Object`.

Es decir que `ToNumber()` sera aplicada a un `object`, por lo tanto se establece el uso de `ToPrimitive()`.

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber

**4) Función `ToPrimitive()`**:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive

Esta función se encuentra en el apartado de conversión de tipos:

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-type-conversion

Y se usara con el fin de convertir el objeto `Object` a un valor primitivo para que pueda ser luego evaluado con:

```
`ToString()` y `valueOf()`.
`valueOf()` y `ToString()`.
```

Respectivamente.

En este caso al ser un Objeto `Object`: se aplica:

```
Type(input)
```

Siguiendo el siguiente orden de evaluación:

*Tabla resumida:*

```
Si PreferredType | no fue pasado | hint = "default".
Si PreferredType | fue pasado    | hint = "string".
Si PreferredType | fue pasado    | hint = "number".
Luego retornar   | OrdinaryToPrimitive(input, hint).
```

Se procede a la conversión:

```
Afirmacion: Type(O) es Object. // Se cumple pues es array[] es un Object.

Afirmacion: Type(hint) es String y su valor es "string" ó "number".
```

En este caso es un `string vacio`.

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#table-12

Cumpliéndose:

```
Si hint = string.
```

Aplicar "`toString()`" y luego "`valueOf()`"

- ToString():

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tostring
>
> `ToPrimitive(argument, hint String)`. // Establecido anteriormente

- valueOf():

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.valueof

Aplicando tenemos que:

```
ToString( array[] ) == ( "" ) // Paréntesis para mejor entendimiento

( "" ).valueOf() == ( "" )
```

- Por lo tanto:

  +[] == ToNumber(array[]).

  ToNumber(array[]) == ( "" ).valueOf().

  ( "" ).valueOf == ( "" ).

Ahora usemos nuestro operador logico not (!) para obtener:

```
( "" ) == false.
```

---

**5) Seguido tocaria sustituir**:

```
if (!+[]+!+[]==2) {
document.write('Somos iguales');
}
else {
document.write('Somos distintos');
}
```

Resolviendo:

```
if (!("")+!("")==2) {
document.write('Somos iguales');
}
else {
document.write('Somos distintos');
}
```

Finalizando:

```
if (true+true==2) {
document.write('Somos iguales');
}
else {
document.write('Somos distintos');
}

HTML: Somos iguales
```

Comment: Que bien , me podrías pasar documentación acerca de los elementos considerados true y todo ese ámbito? porfavor.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: @EduardoSebastian  Deberías de poner esta como la respuesta correcta, ya que considero que es mucho mejor respuesta que la mía.

Comment: Victor: el operador `==` en ciertos casos realiza conversión de los operandos. Para efectos de "comprobación" como las que mencionas en tu respuesta considero que se debería usar `===`  o en su defecto mencionar cómo se debería considerar la conversión realizada por `==`.

Answer (score 4):

Veo que esta pregunta ha generado un grupo de respuestas muy valiosas y es este tipo de preguntas y respuestas las que más nutren a nuestra comunidad. Intentaré aportar mi granito de arena a este maravilloso hilo.

Voy a aclarar ciertos aspectos que no están aclarados. Quien lea las respuestas notará que hay algunas que se contradicen. He visto un comentario de @toledano en la respuesta de @Dev.Joel y otra de @Dev.Joel en la respuesta de @JorgeArturoJuarez básicamente preguntándose por qué `[] == false` es `true` y por otro lado `![]` es `false` y me parece que es debido a varias de las respuestas que son algo ambiguas, como la respuesta marcada como correcta que mostraba que `[]` era igual a `false`.

Lo primero que hay que saber es que toda instancia de un objeto está definida de por sí y por lo tanto es verdadera:

```js
var a = [];
var b = new String("");
var c = new Boolean(false);

if (a && b && c) {

  console.log("todos son verdaderos");
  console.log(!a, !b, !c);
  
}
```

No se deben confundir las instancias de un objeto con los valores primitivos:

```js
var a = "";
var b = false;
var c;

if (a || b || c) {

  console.log("¿hay alguna verdadera?");
  
} else {

  console.log("ninguna es verdaera");
  console.log(!a, !b, !c);
  
}
```

Sin embargo al usar los [operadores de comparación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) (exceptuando `===` y `!==`) y los operandos tener un tipado diferente, `JavaScript` intenta convertir ambos operandos a un tipo apropiado para realizar la comparación, y generalmente esta conversión es numérica. Es por eso que ocurre lo siguiente sin importar que sean instancias de objetos y sean verdaderas:

```js
var a = [];
var b = new String("");
var c = new Boolean(false);

//---Estas comparaciones son verdaderas
console.log(a == false);
console.log(b == false);
console.log(c == false);

//---Esto se debe a que
console.log(+a, +b, +c, +false);
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta se podrá entender por qué `[] == false` da `true` y `![]` da `false`.

En cuanto a la pregunta principal, ya todo está más que explicado en las anteriores respuestas, aquí lo resumo:

1. Al aplicar el [operador unario `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) a una instancia de `Array`
   vacía el resultado es `0` (ya que internamente le aplica [la operación abstracta `ToNumber`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)).
2. Al aplicar [el operador lógico `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#Logical_NOT_(!)) a `0` el resultado es `true` (ya que este operador devuelve `false` si la expresión puede ser evaluada a `true` y en caso contrario devuelve `true`)
3. [Al sumar dos valores booleanos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos#Suma_()) con valor `true` el resultado será
   `2` (ya que al no tratarse de cadenas de caracteres, en vez de concatenar, el operador intentará convertir los operandos a número antes de sumarlos)