# Expresiones JavaScript,¿Cual es la razón de los siguientes resultados?

Tags: javascript

Tengo las siguientes expresiones en *JavaScript* y me gustaría saber, de forma mas detallada, el por qué de sus resultados.

```
[] == ''    // -> true
[] == 0     // -> true
[''] == ''  // -> true
[0] == 0    // -> true
[0] == ''   // -> false
[''] == 0   // -> true

[null] == ''        //true
[null] == 0         //true
[undefined] == ''   //true
[undefined] == 0    //true

[[]] == 0   //true
[[]] ==''   //true  

[[[[[[]]]]]] == 0   //true
[[[[[[]]]]]] == ''  //true

[[[[[[ null ]]]]]] == 0 //true
[[[[[[ null ]]]]]] == 0 //true

[[[[[[ undefined ]]]]]] == 0    //true
[[[[[[ undefined ]]]]]] == 0    //true
```

Mis dudas han surgido a partir de este meme:

[image: meme]

¿Porque esto no debería ser posible?

Comment: [Existe una pregunta que puede ayudar con sus dudas sobre estos detalles de JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66292/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-condicional-if-2-en-javascript/66296#66296)

Comment: @Davlio yo no lo consideraria duplicado ya que las expresiones son distintas, aunque las respuestas si que pueden servir como ayuda. A mi me gustaria una explicación de estas expresiones.

Comment: @Dev.Joel como dices, puede servir de ayuda pero no creo que llegue a poder explicar todo

Comment: @LombardaArda "Todo" no creo que encuentres en un solo lugar, aunque como base como dije antes es más que interesante.

Comment: @Dev.Joel por supuesto, me sirve como base y responde a alguna de las expriesiones, pero ¿Esa respuesta responde a mi pregunta? Yo creo que no, sirve como base, ayuda, punto de inicio pero no como un respuesta, ademas que tambien seria interesante que en la respuesta se comente la gracia del meme .

Comment: "¿Por qué esto no debería ser posible?" el meme simplemente trata de exagerar las conversiones entre datos (cast). Una matriz vacía al convertirse a booleano da `false`, un 0 al convertirse a booleano es false, por lo que `false == false` es cierto (`true`). Podemos meterle tantas dimensiones a la matriz como queramos (`[]`, `[[]]`, `[[[]]]`, etc), seguirá convirtiéndose en siendo false y manteniéndose cierta la igualdad. Igualmente una cadena de caracteres vacía se convierte en `false`. Te podemos dar referencias a las conversiones entre datos, fallarían estrepitosamente con `===`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La explicación es sencilla, el comparador `A==B` funciona de la siguiente manera:

Si el tipo de A es igual al tipo de B, sencillamente comprueba que los valores son iguales.
Si el tipo de A es `null` o `undefined`, la igualdad es verdad si B es `null` o `undefined`, en cualquier otro caso es falsa.
Si los tipos son distintos, primero hace una conversión de A y/o B para que los tipos sean iguales:

```
String A == Number B -> toNumber(A) === Number B

Object A == Number B ->  toString(A) == toString(B) || toNumber(A)  === B
```

Puedes ver el algoritmo completo en la web del [Estándar ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), aunque lo añado aquí:

> 1. Si Type(x) es el mismo que Type(y), entonces devuelve x === y.
> 2. Comparar `null` y `undefined` siempre es `true`
> 3. Si Type(x) es Number y Type(y) es String, devuelve x == ToNumber(y).
> 4. Si Type(x) es String and Type(y) es Number, devuelve ToNumber(x) == y.
> 5. Si Type(x) es Boolean, devuelve ToNumber(x) == y.
> 6. Si Type(y) es Boolean, devuelve x == ToNumber(y).
> 7. Si Type(x) es String, Number, o Symbol y Type(y) es Object, devuelve x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 8. Si Type(x) es Object y Type(y) es String, Number, o Symbol, devuelve  ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 9. En cualquier otro caso, devuelve false.

Como un array es un objeto, tenemos que, al intentar transformarlo en un número, funciona así:

```js
let a=[]; 
let b=[0,1,2];
let c=[2];

console.log(+a); //vacío, devuelve 0
console.log(+b); //muchos valores, Not a Number
console.log(+c); // un valor, se devuelve ese valor
```

Puesto que `[]` se transforma en `0` y `[A]` se transforma en `toNumber(A)`, tenemos que `[[]]` pasa a ser `[0]` que, a su vez, pasa a ser 0.

Por tanto `[[...[]...]]` siempre es cero.

Del mismo modo, `null` y `undefined` se transforman en `0`

Por tanto:

> ¿Porque esto no debería ser posible?

Es posible y una vez que lo *entiendes* tiene cierta lógica. Para evitar comportamientos como éste siempre puedes usar `===`en lugar de `==`. Lo que pasa es que

> [Javascript es el lenguaje más *malentendido* del mundo](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html) - Douglas Crockford, 2001

Comment: Cuando dices: _"Si los tipos son distintos, primero hace una conversión de A y/o B para que los tipos sean iguales"_. ¿Cuál es la prioridad de tipos para realizar la conversión implícita, porqué consideraría `toNumber(A) === Number B` y no `A === toString(B)`?

Comment: @Davlio añado un enlace para responder a tu duda