# por que el valor booleano de indefinido es falso, pero cuando se compara con false da que son diferentes?

Tags: javascript

El caso

```js
var resu;

undefined?  resu = "esto seria inesperado" : resu = "debería dar esto";
   
console.log(resu);
```

Pero cuando voy a confirmar la teoria de que `undefined` es `false`:

```js
var resu;

undefined == false? resu = "deberia dar esto" : resu = "esto seria inesperado";

console.log(resu);
```

Comment: Hola, puedes hallar respuestas a esta pregunta en [¿Cómo funciona el condicional if (!+\[\]+!+\[\] == 2) en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66292/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-condicional-if-2-en-javascript)

Comment: `if(undefined)` tiene su razon de ser ,  es una forma de preguntar si un objeto existe, es muy comun hacer este tipo de validaciones ; a proposito te invito a hacer el [tour] por el sitio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para entender lo que ocurre en tu código lo primero que hay que tener en cuenta es que un operador ternario hace una evaluación booleana de la parte que está a la izquierda del operador (antes del signo `?`).

En este caso o similares:

```
undefined ? "esto seria inesperado" : "debería dar esto";
```

Se hará una evaluación booleana de la parte a la izquierda (`undefined`), como está especificado en el [apartado 7.1.2 de ECMA Script](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-toboolean). **Cuando `undefined` es convertido a booleano, el resultado de esa conversión es `false`.**

Por eso, la expresión toma el valor del extremo derecho, porque la conversión de `undefined` a booleano es igual a `false`.

Aquí por el contrario:

```
undefined == false ? "deberia dar esto" : "esto seria inesperado";
```

se aplica lo especificado en el *algoritmo de comparación de igualdad abstracta*, documentado en el apartado [7.2.13 Abstract Equality Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) de ECMA Script. Estaríamos ante el **caso 7** de dicho algoritmo, que dice: *si el tipo de `y` (valor de la derecha) es booleano, devuelve el resultado de la comparación `x == ToNumber(y)`*. En otras palabras: **convierte `false` a número y compara si ese resultado es igual a `undefined`**. Si convertimos `false` a número, obtenemos un `0`, y la evaluación `undefined==0` da como resultado `false` y por tanto la expresión toma el valor del extremo derecho.

Fíjate que si fuerzas una conversión de `undefined` y preguntas si es igual a `false`, entonces sí el operador ternario evaluaría como `true`, porque sería lo mismo que preguntar `false==false`:

```
Boolean(undefined)==false ? "esto seria inesperado" : "debería dar esto";
```

Incluso, si haces una comparación estricta (de tipo y de valor), el resultado sería `true`:

```
Boolean(undefined)===false ? "esto seria inesperado" : "debería dar esto";
```

Observa estos dos ejemplos y saca tus propias conclusiones:

```
Boolean(undefined)==0  ? "esto seria inesperado" : "debería dar esto";
Boolean(undefined)===0 ? "esto seria inesperado" : "debería dar esto";
```

Aquí te dejo un fragmento de código con ejemplos. Para más claridad he usado variables, he impreso su tipo. Verás todo lo dicho más arriba y verás que `undefined` **nunca** es igual a `false`, lo que es igual a `false` sería un eventual conversión de `undefined` a booleano.

```js
var status;
var myUndefined = undefined;
var myBooleanFromUndefined= Boolean(undefined);
console.log("La variable myUndefined es de tipo: "+typeof myUndefined +" \ny su valor es: "+myUndefined);
console.log("La variable myBooleanFromUndefined es de tipo: "+typeof myBooleanFromUndefined +" \ny su valor es: "+myBooleanFromUndefined);


status = myUndefined ? "TRUE: esto seria inesperado" : "FALSE: debería dar esto";
console.log(status);



status = myUndefined == false ? "TRUE: deberia dar esto" : "FALSE: esto seria inesperado";
console.log(status);

status = myBooleanFromUndefined == false ? "*TRUE: deberia dar esto" : "FALSE: esto seria inesperado";
console.log(status);

status = myBooleanFromUndefined === false ? "*TRUE: deberia dar esto" : "FALSE: esto seria inesperado";
console.log(status);

status = myBooleanFromUndefined == 0 ? "*TRUE: deberia dar esto" : "FALSE: esto seria inesperado";
console.log(status);

status = myBooleanFromUndefined === 0 ? "TRUE: deberia dar esto" : "*FALSE: esto seria inesperado";
console.log(status);

status = myUndefined == undefined ? "TRUE: deberia dar esto" : "FALSE: esto seria inesperado";
console.log(status);
```

Comment: `undefined no es igual a false, porque ahí se evalúa tal cual es`. Y porqué `0 == false // =>true` ?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo [según MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) el operador de igualdad convierte los operandos si éstos no son del mismo tipo para aplicar luego una comparación estricta.Si ambos operandos son objetos, entonces JavaScript compara las referencias internas que son iguales cuando los operandos se refieren al mismo objeto en la memoria.

Comment: false es boleano por lo tanto es cero por ese motivo son iguales; los invito a leer esta [buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66292/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-condicional-if-2-en-javascript)

Comment: Eso lo tenía claro, pero, porqué si el operador de igualdad trata de convertir los tipos, con undefined no pasa lo mismo? Si la representación booleana de undefined es false, qué tipo de conversiones según la especificación se realizan?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo en el apartado 7.1.2 (enlace al principio de la respuesta) explica el tipo de conversión que ocurre con el `0`. Dice esto: *Return false if argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise return true.*, por tanto, el ternario fuerza una conversión de tipos (convierte el `0` a booleano, igualando el valor a `false`).

Comment: Me refería a `undefined == false` Revisando por internet he visto que undefined no es convertido, como bien indicas. https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo `undefined` no es convertido en ese caso, como ya había indicado, no obstante, lo que ocurre es que `false` es convertido a número y luego es comparado con `undefined`, como explica el *[algoritmo de comparación de igualdad abstracta](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)* de ECMA Script. Ahí aplica el **caso 7** de dicho algoritmo.

Answer (score 11):

Eso es por que `undefined` no es **falso**, en cambio la representación booleana de `undefined` si que lo es.

```js
console.log(undefined == false)

console.log(Boolean(undefined) == false)

console.log(new Boolean(undefined) == false)

console.log(new Boolean(undefined) == true)
```

Comment: creo que si mejoras tu respuesta, con  [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) te puedes llenar

Comment: Hola, agrega mas información para mejorar la calidad de la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

> Por qué el valor booleano de indefinido es falso, pero cuando se
>   compara con false da que son diferentes?

Tocando el tema de datos booleanos conocemos que su representación lógica es la siguiente:

True que en representación binaria es igual a 1

False que en representacón binaria es igual a 0

Por lo que queda claro que el tipo de dato booleano posee una estructura predefinida y un valor especifico ***asignado*** por defecto en javascript

Que sucede con undefined?

Es un tipo de dato también ([primitivo especial](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=788:tipos-de-datos-javascript-tipos-primitivos-y-objeto-significado-de-undefined-null-nan-ejemplos-cu01112e&catid=78&Itemid=206)), sin embargo, no posee valor ***asignado*** por defecto en el lenguaje. Es utilizado para especificar o reservar un espacio en memoria al cual no se le ha asignado valor alguno.

Es por ello que

`console.log(undefined == false)` no retorna **true**

**False** puede ser tomado como `0`, sin embargo, no es así con **undefined** porque no posee representación numérica en términos de valor asignado, de allí el hecho de que sea un **primitivo especial** porque genera ciertas excepciones en el comportamiento estandar del lenguaje. Yo podría declarar una variable:

```
var x;
```

Aún cuando existe `x`, tiene un espacio reservado en memoria y podría hacer operaciones con ella luego... lo que sucede con la instrucción anterior es que reserva el espacio en memoria para `x` ***pero no está definida*** (es undefined), es decir, no ***tiene representación lógica*** y es por ello:

`console.log(x == false)` tampoco arrojará **true**

Claro que la conversión de tipos de javascript maneja este tipo de excepciones si realizas una comparación estricta de tipo lógica:

`console.log(Boolean(undefined) == false)` si arrojará **true**

Arrojará **true** porque estás obligando a que undefined tome un valor lógico o booleano y el comportamiento por defecto al declararlo un booleano siempre será false salvo tu mismo indiques que no sea así.

Para más información puedes visitar: [undefined-javacript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/undefined) también puedes leer [null vs undefined](https://fernetjs.com/2011/12/null-vs-undefined/)

> Por qué si el operador de igualdad trata de convertir los tipos, con
>   undefined no pasa lo mismo?

Precisamente porque el objetivo de undefined es poder declarar una variable (por ejemplo)  sin que necesariamente se sepa cuál es su tipo. Es por ello que javascript maneja esta especie de excepción a su regla de conversión de tipos indirecta.

Distinto es comparar el booleano de undefined con false:

```
console.log(Boolean(undefined) == false)
```

Con la instrucción anterior estás forzando a una conversión automática de tipos de manera directa así que javascript por defecto "asigna" el valor false en la conversión y `false==false` como resultado es **true**.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

El tema es que `undefined` y `false` (o `true`) son de tipos distintos:

```
> typeof undefined
"undefined"
> typeof false
"boolean"
> undefined == false
false
```

Así que ya ves, ¿por qué serían iguales dos valores de tipos distintos? `undefined` y `boolean` son dos de los tipos primitivos de JavaScript.

Si quieres la representación booleana de `undefined` puedes hacer lo que dice @Iker en su respuesta. Otra forma es usar la doble negación para convertir `undefined` en su representación booleana:

```
> !undefined
true
> !!undefined
false
> !!undefined == false
true
```